# How to automatically refresh canvas after saving layer edits

Tags: qgis, editing, windows-7

After saving a layer edit in QGIS 2.8.2 (Win7) I've to press F5 or change the map section to refresh the canvas. This is quite annoying when working with dynamic PostGIS views. Is there a way to autorefresh the canvas when saving a layer edit? Using QGIS 2.8.2 on Ubuntu everythin is working fine.